# Multiple foreign key to one field

Tags: django, django-models, orm

I have two classes; Devices and Connections. I am trying to create a connection between them.

Device Class;

```
class Devices(models.Model):
    device_no = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    device_name= models.CharField(max_length=512)
```

Connections Class;

```
class Connections(models.Model):
    connection_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    device_name1 = models.CharField(max_length=512)  
    device_name2 = models.CharField(max_length=512) 
    device_no1= models.ForeignKey(Devices, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column="device_no1", related_name="dev1_no")
    device_no2= models.ForeignKey(Devices, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column="device_no2", related_name="dev2_no")
```

*I've changed variable names due to security concerns*

What I am aiming is build a connection between device one to device two. These boths have same specifications. When I use it like this it doesn't return any errors. But when I try to make a query i.e:

```
Connections.objects.filter(device1_no=dev_no)
```

It doesn't return any member of Device class. It only returns Connections class members. I've also tried;

```
Connections.objects.filter(device_no1__device_no=12)
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
for conn in Connections.objects.filter(device_no1=dev_no):
    print(conn.device_no2)
```

Or using reverse relation([**`documentation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/)):

```
for conn in dev_no.dev1_no.all():  # assuming dev_no is a Device instance
    print(conn.device_no2)
```

Comment: After your comment I've realized `Connections.objects.filter(device1_no=dev_no)` is returning device object to device1_no variable. I've accessed `result.device1_no.ne_name` to what I've asked. Thanks for your help.